# Giving wp_list_categories the class of the category

Tags: categories

I am using wp_list_categories to list my categories in my menu. When the menu is generated each category is listed as a `<li>`-element with "cat-item[number]" as class.

Is there a way to also or instead give the `<li>`s the category name as the class? Just like the posts have the category name as the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) instead, so that you can have better control over the output of your list.  And if I recall correctly, `wp_list_categories` calls `get_categories` anyway.  You can use the same `$args` array in either function, and you should get the same categories as a result.

Then you can simply build your own unordered list like so:

```
// build category collection
$categories = get_categories($args);
$menu = '<ul>';

// iterate through your categories
foreach($categories as $category) {

    // you can also use $category->slug
    $menu .= '<li class="' . $category->name . '">' . $category->name . '</li>';

}

$menu .= '</ul>';
echo $menu;
```

Of course, you may build out as much markup to your `<ul>` and `<li>` tags as you wish (additional classes, anchors, etc).

You may even wish to mimic all the other classes that `wp_list_categories` adds (just so that you stay consistent).  And if you use this in multiple places, it might even be good to create your own function.

For a complete reference of which properties are available in your `$category` object [see the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! What if I would like to link to the categories and to use some of the wp_list_categories functions? Like hide_empty?

Comment: It's pretty easy.  Just have a look at those two links in the answer.  For example, on the `get_the_category` Codex page, they have a code sample for getting the link (using `get_category_link($category->term_id )`). And empty categories should be hidden by default (because the `$args` parameter for `get_categories()` has an element called `hide_empty`.

Comment: @ Jacob Cobb - thanks again - and sorry, I somehow missed the link!